# IF statements and Input

Tags: python

I am just practising basic python and attempting to build a calculator with only addition, subtraction, and multiplication functions. When I run the code and input 1, 2, or 3, I get no output.

Here is my code:

```
question1 = input("Enter 1 to add, 2 to substract, or 3 to multiply: ")
if question1 == 1:
    num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
    num2 = input("Enter another number: ")
    result = float(num1) + float(num2)
    print(result)
elif question1 == 2:
    num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
    num2 = input("Enter another number: ")
    result = float(num1) + float(num2)
    print(result)
elif question1 == 3:
    num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
    num2 = input("Enter another number: ")
    result = float(num1) + float(num2)
    print(result))
```

Comment: @Adelin `int(question1)`, not `int("question1")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your input to the integer. Try this code:

```
question1 = int(input("Enter 1 to add, 2 to substract, or 3 to multiply: "))
if question1 == 1:
    num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter another number: "))
    result = num1 + num2
    print(result)
elif question1 == 2:
    num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter another number: "))
    result = num1 - num2
    print(result)
elif question1 == 3:
    num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter another number: "))
    result = num1 * num2
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you get some input with `input()` in Python3, you get a string.

Test it with following:

```
foo = input()
print(type(foo))
```

The result will be `<class 'str'>`(it means `foo`'s type is string) regardless of your input. If you want to use that input as a integer, you will have to change the type to `int`(integer).

You should use `int(input())` to get a integer like the following:

```
question1 = int(input("Enter 1 to add, 2 to substract, or 3 to multiply: "))
```

You have to change the number inputs in each of the `if-else` blocks too:

```
if question1 == 1:
    num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter another number: "))
    result = num1 + num2
    print(result)
```

Or, you can just change it when you want to calculate:

```
num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
num2 = input("Enter another number: ")
...
result = int(num1) + int(num2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are well on your way! As mentioned in the comments, all your statements are False because `input()` just by itself returns string type which will never be equal to an integer.

You just have to change the all the `input()` of your code to convert it as an int to be stored. Below is an example:

```
question1 = int(input("Enter 1 to add, 2 to substract, or 3 to multiply: "))
```